# How to make friends Facebook Log in code with Google log in code

Tags: google-oauth, facebook-php-sdk, social-network-friendship

I have two snippets of code that are each responsible for logging in from their social networks are Facebook and Google.

```
//GOOGLE
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {

    $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);

    //This condition will check there is any error occur during geting authentication token. If there is no any error occur then it will execute if block of code/
    if (!isset($token['error'])) {
        //Set the access token used for requests
        $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

        //Store "access_token" value in $_SESSION variable for future use.
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];

        //Create Object of Google Service OAuth 2 class
        $google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);

        //Get user profile data from google
        $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
        if (!empty($data['sub'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['sub'];
        }
        if (!empty($data['given_name'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $data['given_name'] . " " . $data['family_name'];
        }
        if (!empty($data['email'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_email_address'] = $data['email'];
        }
        if (!empty($data['picture'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_image'] = $data['picture'];
        }
    }
}
```

```
//FACEBOOK
$facebook_helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    } else {
        $access_token = $facebook_helper->getAccessToken();
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
        $facebook->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    $graph_response = $facebook->get("/me?fields=name,email", $access_token);
    $facebook_user_info = $graph_response->getGraphUser();

    if (!empty($facebook_user_info['id'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_image'] = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $facebook_user_info['id'] . '/picture';
    }
    if (!empty($facebook_user_info['id'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $facebook_user_info['id'];
    }
    if (!empty($facebook_user_info['name'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $facebook_user_info['name'];
    }
    if (!empty($facebook_user_info['email'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_email_address'] = $facebook_user_info['email'];
    }
} else {
    // Get login url
    $facebook_permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
    $facebook_login_url = $facebook_helper->getLoginUrl('https://2goe.com/demo/'.$lang.'/home/', $facebook_permissions);
}
```

When they are together, then:

1. When you click Google log in, redirectURL responds with server error 500.
2. And Facebook does not return user data, which is requested in the code.

But if, for example, you delete the code of one of the social networks, it individually works fine. I myself tried to somehow paint 2 codes into one code, but to no avail. I also split them into different files, but this also did not bring any results.

Can you please help me somehow combine them correctly so that there are no such conflicts between them.

Comment: They are both looking for $_GET['code'] what do you think would happen if the Facebook code tried to use the Google Code?  You need to tell your code which one its working with or their both going to try to read it and the one that fails last will over write the one that worked.

Comment: After clicking the log in buttons, they both return me a string like

```?code=....```

I have no idea how to write the code to make each one work. I even somehow tried to write a check through pregmatch, because the line that google returns to me contains the word googleapis

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that they are both returning the same code.

Comment: its google ``` demo/?code=4%2F0AX4XfWjgJg2Ix1u8Uvxg5wFsVZCA8tPVQvPGflxdnS2PrR88RmXjH6cTSErz0CPyctiAJg&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=none``` 

its facebook ```https://2goe.com/demo/ru/home/?code=AQCb0XGT-i34Gzs5WROr0oNQh9nU50PVrxT8TOGt2W3GpHNOCWL_LajB7oqClIpHsDkebelpTH1OLDeCq6nXC2YZpSvJ13igg40dPUTZEGiMjFw13VLfoBsrB1bGU18qUNdr2Tjxnbuf1o5TWlDTYeBv_hCiyoGEh5pv4PScUe2eDG9kQUKK3o5O_QdyRkJXiHLDhx5BaBBMhKNsWjj17l6_nKEwfiOoiXTuktxvizOUrSdnrGu9Ush-#_=_```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are setting things with the same session names.  $_GET['code'] could be facebook or google there is no way for you to know which one it is.

The easiest solution would be to run the google code first.  Then alter the if statement for Facebook a little.

If you do something like this the code for facebook will look for a code find a code but it will also look for an error from Google.  If google spit back an error then you try the code with facebook.  If it did not return an error then you know the code was most likely used by Google.

```
if(isset($_GET['code'] && isset($token['error'])) {
```

Comment: Does not work. I try to change the conditions, like yours, but after that the site itself does not respond at all, it gives an error 500

Comment: please look [edited statement code](https://codeshare.io/X8BVBM)

Comment: Its work, I [edit my code](https://codeshare.io/VZkVy8). Thanks for help

Comment: I have one small problem. why i cant get form google userinfo 'sub'
`$data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['sub'];`
I get email, name, but I can't get 'sub'. In general, I need some kind of user id from google user info

Comment: Googles user info end point is tricky try checking the People api.  People.get(me) should work

Comment: Yes, I found. Thank you for help